# Blender game engine python set position not working correctly

Tags: python, game-engine

When I set a command for change object position on collision with another object, there is a problem. The position changes ok but the object hurls away. Here an [example .blend](http://petercakovsky.com/docasne/ball.rar).

Press arrow key for ball motion. If ball falls on the blue plane, set a change reset position. I do not restart the scene, only change the object's position. I use Blender 2.76

script used:

```
import bge

scene = bge.logic.getCurrentScene()
objList = scene.objects

obj_name = 'CubeNOVE'
cube = objList[obj_name]

cube.worldPosition = [2.75482, 3.59394, 13.89875]
```

Comment: Did you teleport (which is a location change) your object into another static object?

Comment: No Monster. I try use into empty object, but not work

Comment: import bge


def main():

    cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
    own = cont.owner

    scene = bge.logic.getCurrentScene()
    
    spawnPoint = scene.objects ["spawnPoint"]
    
    if own.position.z < 5:
        own.worldPosition = spawnPoint.worldPosition

main()